# Query sum of values between lo and hi for a stream of numbers

Tags: trees

Suppose you have a stream of incoming numbers that you're storing and at any given instant in time, you want to query the sum of values between a given `lo` and `hi` in the stream you've read thus far.

It it possible to solve this problem with segment trees?

The only solution I could come up with is either O(n) insertion and O(log n) query (using a sorted array and prefix sum) or O(log n) insertion and O(n) query (using a binary search tree).

Comment: You already told the answer. Using segment trees, you can get $O(\log n)$ for both insertion and query.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I'm having a hard time seeing how segment tree would work here. I've only used segment trees before for arrays where the size of the array was fixed. Here we have a stream of values. To properly use segment trees, would we have to introduce rebalancing operations each time we make an insertion?

Answer (score 1):

Use an AVL tree $T$ to store the incoming numbers. At every node, $v \in T$ also store the sum of the values of all the nodes in the subtree rooted at $v$. The structure is more like a segment tree.

A range query can be easily answered in $O(\log n)$ time.

For the insertion operation, use the [AVL insertion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/). It takes $O(\log n)$ time. Let $v$ be the newly added node and $u$ be the unbalanced node. Then, you will need to update the sum values of the children and grand children nodes of $u$. That constitutes $O(1)$ update operations. You also need to change the sum values on the nodes that appear on the path from root to $v$. Therefore, this operation also takes $O(\log n)$ time.

---

Maybe a Dynamic Segment tree is a better term for it.